# Rails One Table Multiple Polymorphic Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table (connections) it needs to have multiple Polymorphic Relations. The first one is working but the second gets an error. Here is the layout of the tables. I get this error even if I change `has_many :links, as: :linkable` to `has_many :connection_links, as: :linkable`, thinking that it was some reserved word.

```
class CreateConnections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :connections do |t|
      t.integer     :connectable_id
      t.string      :connectable_type
      t.integer     :linkable_id
      t.string      :linkable_type
      t.boolean     :status_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relations
  belongs_to :connectable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true
end


class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections, as: :connectable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :links, as: :linkable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections, as: :connectable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :links, as: :linkable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When I try to pull the `links` it errors out.

`[2] pry(main)> person.connections
  Connection Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections"  WHERE "connections"."connectable_id" = $1 AND "connections"."connectable_type" = $2  [["connectable_id", 9], ["connectable_type", "Person"]]
=> []`

`[3] pry(main)> person.links
NameError: uninitialized constant Person::Link`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that there is no class called Link - doesn't seem like you have one from what you've shown.

Comment: That's true I don't. But the line `has_many :links, as: :linkable` and the line `belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true` should take care of that (I think).

Comment: However after doing some testing with that in mind you are correct. I changed `has_many :connections, as: :connectable` to `has_many :cons, as: :connectable`. I get a similar error `uninitialized constant Person::Con`.

Comment: I was able to fix it by doing this `has_many :links, as: :linkable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Connection'`